# No such table exists -Sqlite error when writing to database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to write to a table in my sqlite database in android the code I am using is as follows:

```
DBH = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    try {
        DBH.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DBH.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("insert into profile (_id, FirstName) values (1, 'Dave')", null);
    DBH.close();
```

DBH is my database helper class and it creates the database just fine and I've even been able to read from the database so i know its there. The table im trying to write to is profile and i am certain that it does in fact exist but every time i run this i get this error:

```
sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: profile
```

I've tried reading from this table and have been able to get results so I'm pretty much stumped. Anyone got any ideas?

Edit: As requested this is my Database helper class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.ProjectZeus.FitnessWire/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "fitnesswire.db";
private SQLiteDatabase myDB;
private Context  myContext;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context,DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;   
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
    boolean check = checkDataBase();
    if(check){
        //Log.e("Check", "Database exists");
    }else{
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try{
            copyDataBase();
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}


private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer,0,length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
    try{
        String myPath= DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        Log.e("checkDataBase()", "Database doesntexist yet");
    }

    if(checkdb != null){
        checkdb.close();
    }

    return checkdb != null ? true : false ;
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close(){
    if(myDB != null){
        myDB.close();
    }
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: please post your DatabaseHelper class

Comment: you could/should use `db.execSQL()` since `insert` is no query (only `select` is)

Comment: is _id is autoincreament column in the table profile?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the app's data from the phone/emulator and then try again?

Comment: @Nishant unfortunately I didn't make the database im using, But from what i can tell from the schema it is just an integer.

Comment: @slukian ya that was my first idea still get the same error

Comment: @zapl thanks for the db.execlSQL() tip. that did the trick for me. if you could make that an answer i will accept it

Comment: @BeardFace I didn't think that would solve it but if it does... there is a new answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `db.execSQL()` instead of `db.rawQuery()`  since insert is no query (only `SELECT` is)

There is a lot of magic going on in `rawQuery()` - it may change the statement before executed by the database and also tries to build a `Cursor` out of the result. Some part in that process seems to fail.

Answer (score 0):

It Happens some times in Iphone as well... Data base not properly connected.

What we do (that work for us ) is that we remove all the Projects from the Simulator Clean The Project and Compile it...

i m not sure whether it gona work in Android but u can try the same

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be raised when a column doesn't exist (I know, it's not ideal, but that's how it is). So make sure you actually have columns named `_id` and `FirstName` in your table.

Comment: I checked the table, the columns exist, thanks for the tip though